# How to cite multiple sections of book using IEEE Citation Style

Tags: citations, ieee

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis in computer science and use the IEEE Citation Style with LaTeX. There already exists a good BibTeX style file. However this question is not about the style rather the usage.

Let's keep this simple: I use a book for my thesis. There are two possibilities to add it to my bibliography. Either as `@book` or `@inbook`. If I use the first I cannot add a pages reference to it and would just cite it as [1] in my thesis. The later allows me to add pages to this entry. However, I only saw entry like pp. 100-200.

This is fine if I would use this book only for one reference, but I use the book all over. My question is: How do I cite this book / the sections of this book correctly. Should I add multiple @inbook entries for each page reference or should I add a @book entry and cite like [1, pp. 100-200]. Using the `\cite[pp. 100-200]{bookID}` allows me to do that. But is that allowed by IEEE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If youe thesis is going to be published by an IEEE journal or conference, then you should look at that venue's site for instructions on such details. Otherwise, look to your institution's guidelines. If there are none, then you may do what you want. Personally, I would avoid cluttering my BibTeX files with multiple @inbook citations which only differ in the referenced page numbers and use the latter citation reference you suggest if it is supported by the IEEE style file.

Comment: Thx, my institution does not offer any special guidelines. So I think I will talk to my supervisor, which style he prefers. In the end, he corrects the thesis :)